# Unable to display the percentage on the barplot

Tags: pandas, bar-chart, data-science, seaborn

I have build a codes below to show the percentage on top of the barplot. But while running the code the percentage is not displaying.

Can anyone help me out to get percentage on the top of the barplot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
for p in b.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    b.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height + 3,
            '{:1.2f}'.format(height/len(df)),
            ha="center")
```

Comment: Hi Arpit, It works well. However how can i do it for a hue .

Comment: Just provide your hue as `sns.countplot(hue='coolwarm')`